# SQLException caught: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: javascript, mysql, servlets, datepicker

I am making a calendar system, where I can choose between 2 dates, and then get returned how many hours I have been working in this period. The below illustration is for one day. The calendar system looks like this:

> [image: DatePicker]

As you can see I have a Start Date and End Date. From the javascript I should pick up the values and send through to my servlet.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>

  $(function() {
        $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
      });
  </script>

  </head>
<body>
    DatePicker Ajax Post:

    <form method="post" id="myForm" action="../getHoursSQL">
    Start Date:
        <input type="text" name="startDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>                     
    End Date:
        <input type="text" name="endDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="startresult"></div>
    <div id="endresult"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("input[name=endDate]").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(date, instance){            
             var jsonStr = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
              $.ajax({
                  url: "../getHoursSQL",
                  type: "post",
                  data: JSON,
                  success: function(data){
                      start: $("#startDate").val();
                      alert("success");
                      $("#startresult").html(data);

                  },
                  error:function(){
                      alert("failure");
                      $("#startresult").html('there is error while submit');
                  }  
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And My servlet is here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{



        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            //Load database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            //Getting the data from database

            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + "WHERE startDate = ? AND endDate = ? ";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

            java.util.Date util_StartDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("startDate") );  
            java.sql.Date sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Date( util_StartDate.getTime() );

            java.util.Date util_EndDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("endDate") );      
            java.sql.Date sql_EndDate = new java.sql.Date( util_EndDate.getTime() );
                pst.setDate( 1, sql_StartDate );
                pst.setDate(2, sql_EndDate );
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("startDate"));                          
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("endDate"));
            //Show the result from database
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            float Allday_hours_sum = 0;
                while (rs.next()){                                      
                    Allday_hours_sum += rs.getFloat("Allday_hours"); 

                }   
                res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
                res.getWriter().print(Allday_hours_sum); 

                pst.close();

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that when I run my page I get an error SQLException caught: Unknown column 'startDate'in 'where clause'. My database looks like this:

```
          P_id   |     Date         |   Day_hours    |        Day_minutes   |     Allday_hours  
Job 1      1        2014-03-10              4                      45                 4.45
Job 2      2        2014-03-10              5                      15                 5.15
Job 3      3        2014-03-09              3                      30                 3.30
Job 4      4        2014-03-09              1                      45                 1.45

                                                                   Printet out:     **15.15**
```

That is of course because I don't have any "startDate" in my database. But How can I make the following SQL query to pick up the dates?

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                        + "WHERE startDate = ? AND endDate = ? ";
```

When I hit "Submit" i get this printet in my console:

2014-03-03
2014-03-21

```
SQLException caught: Unknown column 'startDate' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Space before `WHERE` keyword, like below,

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + " WHERE Date Between ? AND ? ";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I still get the error: 2014-03-10
2014-03-26
SQLException caught: Unknown column 'startDate' in 'where clause', because I do not have a column called startDate in my MySQL

Comment: @Julie24 very easy, just remove startDate  to Date and endDate to Date and done. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: That is full cool, then I only get printet the dates. Another problem came, but the most important thing is this. Thanks a lot Kedarnath :-)

Comment: @Julie24: When a value has to be checked on a single column using `where` clause, `AND` wont fetch any records. This is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + " WHERE Date = ? AND Date = ? ";
```

Comment: No. This is not correct. It would not fetch any results. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have columns with name `startDate` and `endDate` but `date`.
And hence is the SQL Exception thrown.

Change:

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours
              FROM Workdata "
           + "WHERE startDate = ? AND endDate = ? ";
```

To:

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours
              FROM Workdata "
           + "WHERE Date = ? AND Date = ? ";
```

And when you have only `Date` column, you can't use `AND` on it in `where` clause.
It won't happen ever.

You must be looking for either *either - or* or a *between* clause.

**Example**:
Change:

```
WHERE Date = ? AND Date = ?
```

To:

```
WHERE Date IN ( ?, ? )
```

Or

```
WHERE Date between ? and ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is passed two variables. Try referring to them as either `{0}` and `{1}`, or use the names from javascript `startDate` and `endDate`.

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN {0} and {1}
```

or,

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

Comment: Verify your answer in my opinion error refers to invalid column in table.